# Help me run the numbers on a perfect IV ditto

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

So I am currently playing Pokémon Sun version and am attempting to collect a ditto with perfect IVs. I’m using the SOS battle method with an Alola raticate that knows hidden power. It has only one resistance which is dark type because I know a hidden power from a Pokémon with perfect IVs is a dark move. So I’m calling any ditto using a hidden power (dark) a pseudo perfect ditto. Only after I check it in the computer do I know if it’s truly perfect.

So my question is this. Given that every ditto caught is guaranteed to have at least 4 perfect IVs and guaranteed to have a dark type hidden power, what is the possibility space? How many pseudoperfect ditto can I expect on average to catch in order to find a true perfect ditto?

Comment: The type of hidden power can be shortened to the odd or even-ness of the IV. Given that you have 4 perfect IVs, that indicates that 4/6 of these IVs are odd. Hidden power dark occurs when you have all odd IVs, so the last two IVs must be odd (1/16 chance). This suggests there is a 1/256 of a "pseudo-perfect" ditto being perfect.

Comment: @KevinL okay, that’s a higher number than I was hoping for but I’m glad to know what I’m up against.

Comment: @KevinL Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I was on my phone and wasn't able to type up a complete answer

Comment: @KevinL That's no reason to post an answer in a comment. That was a fully-fledged answer, so it should've been posted as such.

Comment: This might be Offtopic, but if you have something rare to offer, I can trade you a 6 IV japanese ditto.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/BreedingDittos/

Comment: @YUNOWORK I have a full set of starters from all generations I can trade. What were you wanting to get for your ditto?

Comment: @YUNOWORK I can also offer a mystery gift code for a Marshadow.

Comment: I'm VERY interested in that marshadow code. Can i still redeem that tho? I thought it was limited to the 30. oct.

Comment: @YUNOWORK According to the card, the code expires on Feb 23 of 2018. Might as well give it a try, right? Is there a way I can contact you and send you the code privately?

Comment: @YUNOWORK And it comes with a Marshadium Z to boot.

Comment: @ShilohPell You can reach me via Steam http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198128071945 - the profile is currently private, but I'll set it to public once I'm at home, so in ~ 4 hours. If you don't have steam, offer something else. In case of emergency, we can always fall back to emails. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: This answer does not go into the base power calculation of hidden power, as gen 6 and above normalized hidden power's base power to 60.

The [type of hidden power is determined by the least significant bit (or odd/even-ness) of each of your IVs](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hidden_Power_(move)/Calculation]) by the formula

```
let a, b, c, d, e, f = HP, Atk, Def, SpA, SpD, Spd IV mod 2
type = Floor( (a+2*b+4*c+8*d+16*e+32*f) * 15 / 64 )
```

where the resulting number `type` is an integer from 0-15, and the type number is mapped to a hidden power type. Since we are looking at hidden power dark, we want a `type` of 15, which is only possible when `a,b,c,d,e,f` are all odd, or the pokemon's HP, Attack, Defense, Special Attack, Special Defense, Speed IVs are all odd.

Given that you are chaining pokemon, 4/6 of your IVs are 31, or odd. This leaves 2 IVs that are evenly distributed over [0-31]. Since you know the pokemon's hidden power type is dark, the non-perfect IVs are (1,3,5,7.... 31). There is a 1/16 chance for each of the two IVs to be 31, or 1/16*1/16 = 1/256 chance that both are 31 (0.390625%) and you have a perfect pokemon.

Comment: Aww yiss, maths.